# Not able to download generated pdf using ajax

Tags: ajax

I m using ajax which first generate pdf based on jsp data using itext library.My pdf is generating on server but not able to download that pdf.
I want to do it by jquery ajax b'coz i don't want jsp page to get refreshed.

I m calling this function on clicking download button

```
function download()
    {
        alert("down");
      var e = document.getElementById("companyName");
        var company = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var billNo=$("#billNo").val();
  var billDate=$("#billDate").val();
  alert(billDate);
  var totalAmount=$("#totalAmount").val();
  var amount=$("#amount").val();
  var discount=$("#discount").val();
  var tax=$("#tax").val();
  var subTotal=$("#subTotal").val();
    var dataObj = { 
            "companyName":company,
            "billNo":billNo,
            "billDate":billDate,
            "totalAmount":totalAmount,
            "amount":amount,
            "discount":discount,
            "tax":tax,
            "subTotal":subTotal,
            data : [] 
        };
  var table = document.getElementById("tableId");

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) 
  {

     var row = table.rows[i];
     var value=row.cells[2].innerHTML;

          var jsonData = {};
        var columnName = "itemName";
        var columnName1="itemPrice";
        var column2="quantity";
          jsonData[columnName] =row.cells[1].innerHTML ;
          jsonData[columnName1] = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
          jsonData[column2] = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
          dataObj.data.push(jsonData);
  }
  var data1=JSON.stringify(dataObj);
    console.log(dataObj);
    console.log(data1); 

    $.ajax({
    url: "downloadbill",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:data1,
    type: 'POST',
    datatype:'json',
    async: true,
    success: function (res) {
    alert("downloaded Successfully");   
    }
    });  
    }
```

Action in struts.xml

```
 <action name="downloadbill" class="client.user.bill.action.DownloadIssueBillAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="json">
        <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
      <result type="stream">
       <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param> 
  </result>
 </action>
```

DownloadIssueBillAction

```
public class DownloadIssueBillAction implements ModelDriven<Bill>,      ServletRequestAware
{
Bill bill=new Bill();
private String billNo;
private String companyName;
private String billDate;
private String totalAmount;
private String amount;
private String discount;
private ArrayList<Bill> data;
private String subTotal;
private String tax;
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;
private InputStream inputStream;
private String fileName;
private long contentLength;
public String execute() throws FileNotFoundException 
{
     try {

         String filePath = servletRequest.getRealPath("/");
         System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
         File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, "Neeraj"+getBillNo()+".pdf");
         OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreate);
         Document document = new Document();
         PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);



       PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);


       PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Name"));
       c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
       c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
       table.addCell(c1);

       c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Quantity"));
       c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
       c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
       table.addCell(c1);

       c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Price"));
       c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
       c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
       table.addCell(c1);
       table.setHeaderRows(1);

       for(int x=0; x<data.size(); x++){

           c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(x).getItemName(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 8)));
           c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
           c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
           table.addCell(c1);
           c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(x).getQuantity(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 8)));
           c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
           c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
           table.addCell(c1);
           c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(x).getItemPrice(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 8)));
           c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
           c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
           table.addCell(c1);




           }
                 table.setSpacingBefore(30.0f);       // Space Before table starts, like margin-top in CSS
                 table.setSpacingAfter(30.0f);

                 PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
               c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SUB TOTAL:"+getSubTotal(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));
               c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
               c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
               table2.addCell(c1);
               c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("      TAX:"+getTax(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));
               c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
               c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
               table2.addCell(c1);
               c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("   AMOUNT:"+getAmount(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));
               c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
               c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
               table2.addCell(c1);
               c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" DISCOUNT:"+getDiscount(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));
               c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
               c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
               table2.addCell(c1);
               c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("    TOTAL:"+getTotalAmount(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10)));
               c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
               c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
               table2.addCell(c1);



        //Now Insert Every Thing Into PDF Document
            document.open();//PDF document opened........                   
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);   //Something like in HTML :-)
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph("Neeraj Industries Pvt Ltd"); 
    preface.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

               document.add(preface);

               Paragraph preface1 = new Paragraph("Bill No"+getBillNo(),new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16)); 
               preface1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

                          document.add(preface1);

                          PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
                          PdfPCell cellOne = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Client Name:"+getCompanyName(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
                          PdfPCell cellTwo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date:"+getBillDate(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
                          cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                          cellTwo.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                          cellOne.setHorizontalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                          cellOne.setPadding (10.0f);
                          cellTwo.setHorizontalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                          cellTwo.setPadding (10.0f);
                          table1.setSpacingBefore(30.0f);       // Space Before table starts, like margin-top in CSS


                          table1.addCell(cellOne);
                          table1.addCell(cellTwo);
                          document.add(table1);
                          document.add(table);
                          document.add(table2);


            document.close();

                    file.close();

       System.out.println("Pdf created successfully..");


     setInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToCreate));
       setFileName(fileToCreate.getName());
       setContentLength(fileToCreate.length());
 System.out.println("File to create :"+fileToCreate.getName());

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
return "success";
}
@Override
public Bill getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bill;
}

public String getBillNo() {
    return billNo;
}
public void setBillNo(String billNo) {
    this.billNo = billNo;
}
public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}
public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}
public String getBillDate() {
    return billDate;
}
public void setBillDate(String billDate) {
    this.billDate = billDate;
}
public String getTotalAmount() {
    return totalAmount;
}
public void setTotalAmount(String totalAmount) {
    this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
}
public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
public String getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}
public void setDiscount(String discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}
public ArrayList<Bill> getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(ArrayList<Bill> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public String getSubTotal() {
    return subTotal;
}
public void setSubTotal(String subTotal) {
    this.subTotal = subTotal;
}
public String getTax() {
    return tax;
}
public void setTax(String tax) {
    this.tax = tax;
}


      //add the call to the table
@Override

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
}
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}
public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
public long getContentLength() {
    return contentLength;
}
public void setContentLength(long contentLength) {
    this.contentLength = contentLength;
}


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
Just do a normal page load of the PDF and the browser may not unload the current page. Depends on the browser.

Or, create an iframe in javascrpt and add it to the page. Set the src to the URL of the PDF to download.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at another website that does downloads and see how they do it.  Like sourceforge, or somthing else